# TableCell image corruption

Tags: ios, git, uitableview, uiimage

I've been working on a little project of mien recently and trying to use this TableView I found on GitHub:
https://github.com/nicolasgomollon/NGDynamicGradientCell

Unfortunately I'm not able to make it work as you can see on this Git:
https://github.com/aout/TestForCells

It seems something is terribly wrong with the way I use it and particularly with the images.
Without images everything works fine but when I add them I can't create any cells.

here's a bit of code:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
    [self setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    maskFill = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mask-fill.png"];
    maskFill = [maskFill resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)];

    bubbleImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bubble-min.png"];
    bubbleMaskImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mask-bubble-min.png"];
    bubbleEdgeInsetsSent = UIEdgeInsetsMake(17.0f, 20.0f, 17.0f, 26.0f);
    bubbleEdgeInsetsReceived = UIEdgeInsetsMake(17.0f, 26.0f, 17.0f, 20.0f);

    bubbleMaskImage = [bubbleMaskImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:bubbleEdgeInsetsSent];

    grayView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [grayView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [grayView setTintColor:RGBA(229.0f, 229.0f, 234.0f, 1.0f)];
    [grayView setAlpha:0.0f];
    [self.contentView addSubview:grayView];

    messageLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [messageLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [messageLabel setFont:[UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody]];
    [messageLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    [messageLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [self.contentView addSubview:messageLabel];
}
return self;
 }

  + (CGFloat)heightForMessage:(NSString *)message
    {
  UIFont *messageFont = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];
  CGSize messageConstraints = CGSizeMake(190.0f, MAXFLOAT);
CGSize messageSize = [message boundingRectWithSize:messageConstraints              options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin    attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : messageFont
     }
  context:nil].size;
CGFloat messageHeight = MAX(35.0f, 10.0f + roundf(messageSize.height) + 5.0f);
return messageHeight + kMessagePadding;
  }

   - (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, image.scale);

[image drawInRect:CGRectSetSize(CGRectZero, newSize)];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return newImage;
  }

  - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
[super drawRect:rect];

[messageLabel setFont:[UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody]];
[messageLabel setTextColor:self.sent?[UIColor whiteColor]:[UIColor blackColor]];

CGSize messageConstraints = CGSizeMake(190.0f, MAXFLOAT);
CGSize messageSize = [messageLabel.text boundingRectWithSize:messageConstraints                                                  options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin  attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : messageLabel.font} context:nil].size;

CGFloat originX = 18.0f + kBubbleEdgeInset;
if (self.sent)
    originX = self.bounds.size.width - messageSize.width - originX;

[messageLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(originX, 7.0f, messageSize.width, messageSize.height)];

CGFloat messageWidth = MAX(48.0f, 13.0f + roundf(messageSize.width) + 18.0f);
CGFloat messageHeight = MAX(35.0f, 10.0f + roundf(messageSize.height) + 5.0f);

if (self.sent) {
    UIImage *maskImage = [self imageWithImage:bubbleMaskImage scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(messageWidth, messageHeight)];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, 0.0f);

    // Draw the bubble mask image.
    [maskImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(self.bounds.size.width - messageWidth - kBubbleEdgeInset, 0.0f, messageWidth, messageHeight)];

    // Draw the message label text (since it'll be masked out).
    [messageLabel.text drawInRect:messageLabel.frame
                   withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : messageLabel.font,
                                    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : messageLabel.textColor}];

    // Draw the mask fill image to the left of the bubble mask image.
    [maskFill drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.bounds.size.width - messageWidth - kBubbleEdgeInset, self.bounds.size.height)];

    // Draw the mask fill image to the right of the bubble mask image.
    [maskFill drawInRect:CGRectMake(self.bounds.size.width - kBubbleEdgeInset, 0.0f, kBubbleEdgeInset, self.bounds.size.height)];

    // Draw the mask fill image in the remaining space below the bubble mask image.
    [maskFill drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0f, messageHeight, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height - messageHeight)];

    // Get everything we drew as an image that we can use to mask the cell with.
    UIImage *imageMask = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    CALayer *maskLayer = [CALayer layer];

    [maskLayer setContents:(id)imageMask.CGImage];
    [maskLayer setFrame:self.bounds];

    [self.layer setMask:maskLayer];
} else {
    [grayView setFrame:CGRectMake(kBubbleEdgeInset, 0.0f, messageWidth, messageHeight)];

    UIImage *maskImage = bubbleImage;
    maskImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:maskImage.CGImage scale:maskImage.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUpMirrored];
    maskImage = [maskImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:bubbleEdgeInsetsReceived];
    maskImage = [self imageWithImage:maskImage scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(messageWidth, messageHeight)];
    maskImage = [maskImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];

    [grayView setImage:maskImage];
}

[messageLabel setAlpha:!self.sent];
[grayView setAlpha:!self.sent];
}

 - (UILabel *)textLabel {
return messageLabel;
  }

  - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
[super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

// Configure the view for the selected state
  }

  @end
```

Any Help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the correction here:
https://github.com/nicolasgomollon/NGDynamicGradientCell/issues/2

Two main problems:
- ARC compatibility to be turned off
- Display update to be done